# kubernetes azure app gateway ingress controller with external and internal pathing

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-application-gateway

We are trying to set up a replacement kube cluster that has a couple of micro services on it but the majority of code still lives in a cloud service. We are using the app-gateway ingress controller as our routing mechanism.  Is it possible to have an app gateway ingress controller route all requests to the external (does not live in the kub cluster) resource except those paths as defined for the micoroservices? And if so, how do we go about setting it up?

this is dotnetcore for linux with helm as the orchestration.

the layout would look something like this...

- default: `/*` => cloud service
- microservice 1: `/ms1/route1` or `/ms1/route2` => internal kube deployment 1
- microservice 2: `/ms2/route1` => internal kube deployment 2

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have an app gateway ingress controller route all
>   requests to the external (does not live in the kub cluster) resource
>   except those paths as defined for the micoroservices?

I don't think it's possible to route the requests to the resources that outside the Kubernetes. You can take a look at [What is Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress):

Ingress exposes HTTP and HTTPS routes from outside the cluster to services within the cluster. Traffic routing is controlled by rules defined on the Ingress resource.

```
     internet
        |
   [ Ingress ]
   --|-----|--
   [ Services ]
```

I think you can route the outside requests to your microservices or your Kubernetes services through [Azure Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview).

Answer (score 0):

it is possible. create a [service with selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors) or [external service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname) and point it to your cloud service and route requests from `/*` to it.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: name
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: url-goes-here
```

Comment: It appears that the type "ExternalName" is not supported by the Azure Application Gateway. Despite multiple attempts, the backend pool is not being created.
Refer:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78045681/aks-ingress-with-service-type-externalname-to-azure-static-website-getting-e/78046166#78046166